# AS3: Z buffering

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, zbuffer

Z buffering is a better rendering technique compared to z sorting, since it can render intersecting 3D objects.

Say, I have an `Array` containing two `Object` instances as following:

```
{v1:new Vector3D(0, 0, 0), v2:new Vector3D(100, 0, 0), v3:new Vector3D(100, 0, 100)}
{v1:new Vector3D(0, 100, 50), v2:new Vector3D(100, 100, 50), v3:new Vector3D(100, 0, 100)}
```

Those are two `Object` instances, each containing three `Vector3D` instances that represent the three vertices of a triangle.

I'll use `Matrix3D.transformVector()` and `Vector3D.project()` to draw the triangles with the `graphics` property of the stage.

When under such circumstances without any sprites created, how can I use Z buffering to draw out each pixel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with you. I miss z-buffering in pure AS3. At this point there is no z buffering provided for Flash/ActionScript-3. Your current options are:

- [Reordering sprites](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS18334A17-3F85-4d5a-ADB4-F5BF6196774C.html)
- [Culling](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WSB0132CAB-C91D-4cb4-9A47-394C85677E40.html)
- [File a request about z-buffering to Abobe](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform)

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to provide two links which are fairly enough to pick up the logic behind z-sorting:

http://www.infiniteturtles.co.uk/blog/fast-sorting-in-as3
http://www.simppa.fi/blog/the-fastest-way-to-z-sort-and-handle-objects-in-as3/

These are well described articles so won't be too hard to understand the idea. Even the source codes is provided.

Comment: OP is not z-sorting, they are z-buffering.

Comment: I need information about Z buffering, thank you. You might want to post your answer to somewhere else, since here it is as useless as nothing.